# Разбить строку по 6 символов

Tags: python, строки

Подскажите пожалуйста простой элегантный способ разбить строку по 6 символов.
Конечно можно сделать это в цикле, но может есть какой-то способ попроще?

*Входящие данные:*

```
x = '100101011100011111101001011000011110'
```

*В результате должна получиться строка:*

```
r = '100101 011100 011111 101001 011000 011110'
```

Comment: ассоциация: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9475241/split-string-every-nth-character

Comment: @splash58, подкорректировал комментарий для https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4857/178988

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно так с помощью регулярных выражений:

```
import re
x = '100101011100011111101001011000011110'
print(re.sub('(.{6})', r'\1 ', x))
```

Answer (score 2):

Можно просто послайсить:

```
r = ' '.join([x[i:i+6] for i in range(0, len(x), 6)])
```

`range(0, len(x), 6)` - `[0, 6, 12, ...]`

Comment: Ну да, это самый популярный ответ :)))

Comment: В смысле? Из двух ответов возрастом 20мин и 0 голосов каждый, этот самый популярный? Моя не понимать

Comment: так первый коммент под вопросом

Comment: Там ссылка на подобный вопрос на enSO, закрытый, как дубликат ещё одной...
 Зачем ходить на enSO за решением тривиальной задачи? Почему не ответили сами?

Comment: пусть автор выбирает - там с десяток вариантов. Переписывать их же - еще более зачем ? :)