# Группировка байт в слова Python

Tags: python, bytearray

Есть ли в Python метод для группировки байт в слова? Пример в изображении снизу.
Байты
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Слова
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/740231

Comment: @andreymal не совсем то, там операции со строкой, тут же арифметические операции идут. Даже если сгруппировать по 4 символа то последовательности будут различаться в примере

Comment: О каких «арифметических операциях» речь? На вашем скриншоте я не вижу ничего, что я мог бы назвать арифметическими операциями, зато вижу байтовые строки

Comment: Если же вы имеете в виду, что хотите декодировать little endian в числа или что-то подобное, то значит так и надо было написать в тексте вопроса

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[array.array](https://docs.python.org/3/library/array.html#array.array) или [struct.iter_unpack](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html#struct.iter_unpack):

```
import array
import struct


b = bytes((0x03, 0x00, 0x49, 0x01, 0xe0, 0xa1, 0x42, 0x09))
print(*(f'{v:02x}' for v in b))
a = array.array('H', b)
print(*(f'{w:04x}' for w in a))
s = tuple(struct.iter_unpack('<H', b))
print(*(f'{w[0]:04x}' for w in s))
```

> ```
> $ python unpack.py
> 03 00 49 01 e0 a1 42 09
> 0003 0149 a1e0 0942
> 0003 0149 a1e0 0942
> ```

Comment: Спасибо большое!